# Android Nougat: Strange behaviour of HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, url, special-characters, httpurlconnection, android-7.0-nougat

I have a strange behaviour with android-7.0-nougat (P8 Lite 2017).
With all previous releases there was no problem.

To conrol iTunes I send messages via `HttpURLConnection`.

I was wondering why the control is not working for some functionality. 
I look via Wireshark to the connection.

Example: (How it's working with Android < 7)
To open the content of an album I have to send following to iTunes:

> http://192.168.111.198:3689/databases/78/...&type=music&sort=album&query=(('com.apple.itunes.mediakind:1','com.apple.itunes.mediakind:32')+
>   'daap.songalbumid:11777812807525111312')

What Android 7 did:

> http://192.168.111.198:3689/databases/78/...&type=music&sort=album&query=((%27com.apple.itunes.mediakind:1%27,%27com.apple.itunes.mediakind:32%27)+
>   %27daap.songalbumid:11777812807525111312%27)

You can see that only `'` changed to `%27`.

Here to Code: (Important parts)

```
        String temp = String
                .format(Locale.US,
                        "%s/databases/%d/containers/%d/items?session-id=%s&meta=dmap.itemname,dmap.itemid,daap.songvotecount,daap.songyear,daap.songgenre,daap.songartist,daap.songalbum,daap.songtime,daap.songuserrating,daap.songtracknumber,dmap.containeritemid&type=music&sort=album&query=(('com.apple.itunes.mediakind:1','com.apple.itunes.mediakind:32')+'daap.songalbumid:%s')",
                        session.getRequestBase(), session.databaseId, session.libraryId, session.sessionId, albumid);

        byte[] raw = RequestHelper.request(temp, false, 10000);


public static byte[] request(String remoteUrl, boolean keepalive, int timeout) throws Exception {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    URL url = new URL(remoteUrl);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);

    connection.setRequestProperty("Viewer-Only-Client", "1");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Client-Daap-Version", "3.11");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");

    if (!keepalive) {
        connection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
        connection.setReadTimeout(timeout);
    } else {
        connection.setReadTimeout(0);
    }
    connection.connect();       

    if (connection.getResponseCode() >= HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED)
        throw new Exception("HTTP Error Response Code: " + connection.getResponseCode());
```

All time in the debugger the `%27` is not visible.
Only after `connection.getResponseCode()` I see this on Wireshark.

Comment: Considering that `'` is a reserved URL character, it should be percent-encoded: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding.

Comment: Tell this Apple! To control iTunes I !have! to send it.

Comment: I don't have any dealings with Apple. Apparently, you do. So, *you* tell them that their URL system is broken and needs to be repaired.

Answer (score 0):

Look like for an error in Nougat itself:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37109069